Can't read environment variables from Nextjs project
EDIT:
If you're naming the env correctly in a Dockerfile but it's still not working, you need to set it BEFORE building the project.

I'm having trouble setting and reading environment variables in a NextJS project.
I have two console logs:
console.log('env', process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log('backend url', process.env.BACKEND_URL);

Running the code without doing anything returns what I expected:
env development
backend url undefined

Exporting variables like this:
NODE_ENV=production
BACKEND_URL=url

Not only prints the previous values, but it also shows the following message in the console:

⚠ You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment.
This creates inconsistencies in the project and is strongly advised
against. Read more:
https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env

Exporting like this:
export NODE_ENV=production
export BACKEND_URL=url

Also prints the same, including the warning.
Running NodeJS like this:
BACKEND_URL=url NODE_ENV=production npm run dev 

Prints the same. echoing the vars prints the correct values.
It's not just the console.logs, I try to use these values in other parts of the code and they act as if these values are still development and undefined.
I have also tried with a .env file:
NODE_ENV=production
BACKEND_URL=url

I can see that it's being read because, when I start the NextJS server, I see the following:
next dev -p 8080

▲ Next.js 14.1.4
- Local:        http://localhost:8080
- Environments: .env

When the file doesn't exist, the line where it says Environment: .env doesn't appear.
Finally, I have checked ~/.bashrc and ~/.zshrc, and they don't have any mentions of NODE_ENV or BACKEND_URL.
What could be happening?

Hey, if you're calling out the env variables on the frontend, you have to add NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix on the variables. Check more info here - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

Now I feel silly. Thank you! If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it

haha, thanks! Glad to hear that it could help you!

If you're calling out the env variables on the frontend (I assume so), you have to add NEXT_PUBLIC_ prefix on the variables.
Check more info on their official doc here - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

You don't have to export variables in .env file.
You just do declare variables like this:
NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ENV=production
NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL=https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env

You don't need to put the variable value into any quotation mark even though it is a String.
P.S. There is a convention of naming variables in .env file: All variable identities should be in uppercase and there should be a prefix of "NEXT_PUBLIC_".
Then you can use these variables in your code as the following:
...
process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL
...

The most important point is that you should be careful not to make .env file public like normal files.
